# how to run javascript function when click on image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

i have this html:

```
<ul class="cont_ul4">

<li class="cont_li">
<div class="cont_picture">
<a href=""><img src="1.jpg" width="150" height="225" ></a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="cont_li">
<div class="cont_picture">
<a href=""><img src="2.jpg" width="150" height="225" ></a>
</div>
</li>

</ul>
```

and this function:

```
function ajax_request() {
$('#placeholder').html('<p><img class="loader" src="/loader.gif"></p>');
$('#placeholder').load("/test.php?id=1234556");
}
```

what i need is when i click on the image to trigger this function.

with an input button i could do this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="ajax_request()" value="Click Me!" />
```

any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Just assign a `click()` event handler to it: http://api.jquery.com/click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your image an id:

```
<img id="myImage" src="1.jpg" width="150" height="225" style="cursor:pointer">
```

Then in Javascript:

```
$("#myImage").click(ajax_request);
```

Or if you want to run the same function for all images:

```
$("img").click(ajax_request);
```

However it would be better to give your images a CSS class and then use that. That way you can restrict the click action to specific images:

```
<img class="link-image" src="1.jpg" width="150" height="225">
...
<img class="link-image" src="2.jpg" width="150" height="225">
```

Then:

```
$(".link-image").click(ajax_request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you lookin for something like this?:

```
$(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
        ajax_request();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @James Johnson... that's just what I was looking for but not for Ajax. With some minor changes: `$('#usedSince').datepicker('setDate', null);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS:

```
function ajax_request() {
   $('#placeholder').html('<p><img class="loader" src="/loader.gif"></p>');
   $('#placeholder').load("/test.php?id=1234556");
}


$('#run_ajax').click(ajax_request);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id='run_ajax' value="Click Me!" />
```